# Angular - I want to split a service into several services but share the same data

Tags: javascript, angular, instance, angular-services

I have a service that is 1000 lines long, I would like to split it into several services but I need to share some data between these different services.

```
@Injectable()
export class ServiceParent {
  toto = new Toto(),
}

@Injectable()
export class ServiceChild extend ServiceParent {

  init() {
    this.toto.doSomething();
  }
}

@Component()
export class myComponent {

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('this.ServiceChild.init()') // return undefined
  }
}
```

How to solve this problem ?

Thanks ^^

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a global variable.

```js
let toto = new Toto();

@Injectable()
export class Service1 {

  init() {
    this.toto.doSomething();
  }
}


@Injectable()
export class Service2 {

  init() {
    this.toto.doSomething();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello,
This is not exactly what I want, I would rather have how to inject my services into my component, and that it shares the same instance.

Declaring my variable as let unfortunately does not solve my problem. But thanks anyway

Comment: You have to provide this services to be available in root simply update your decorator to 
`@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})`

Comment: Hello,
Thank you for your answer. I had already tried to go through the `root` but console.log('this.ServiceChild.init()') always returns me undefined. Looks like it's not sharing the same instance. I tried several methods but without success. Maybe there is a way to provide my services by declaring a dependency like
providers: [
{ provide: '', useClass, deps: [] }
]

Comment: So there is only one way create a instance in constructor of a 1st service. i.e. In service 2 `constructor(private service1: Service1) {}` you will get the shared variable through the service.

Comment: yes, that's what i did for now, but i was hoping there is another way to do it :( thanks for your help